# Pick image from gallery and give text with google API (BitmapFactory.decompileFile null error)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am making text recognition app. I need to pick an image from a gallery and get the text from that image.

I am using this library: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.1`

My code works when i use

```
final Bitmap bitmap = new BitmapFactory(
```

getApplicationContext().getResurce(), R.drawable,image)

but I need to select the image from a gallery.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
  Button button;
  TextView textView;
  ImageView imageView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder((getApplicationContext())).build();
            if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                Log.w("ERROR", "Decetor are not yet available");
            } else {

                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> items = textRecognizer.detect(frame);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
                textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }
    });

  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        try {
            final Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
            imageView.setBitmapImage(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }    
}
```

Logcat :

> Process: com.example.dusan.testphotolatorproject, PID: 27608                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame$Builder.setBitmap(Unknown Source                                                                                             at com.example.dusan.testphotolatorproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this junk:

```
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

Replace it with:

```
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
```

Also:

- Do not call `findViewById()` twice for the `ImageView`, as you are doing now
- Do not call `setImageBitmap()` twice, as you are doing now
- Move this logic into a background thread, or use an image-loading library (e.g., Picasso, Glide), as right now you are doing disk I/O and bitmap processing on the main application thread

Comment: Can you give me code?What is openInputStream ?? and how to move it into backgorund thread?

Comment: @DusanCulum: "What is openInputStream" -- sorry, I forgot the `getContentResolver()` before that. `openInputStream()` is a method on a `ContentResolver`; you get one of those by calling `getContentResolver()` on your activity. See the updated answer.

Comment: @DusanCulum: Call `setImageBitmap()` on the `ImageView`, after your call to `decodeStream()`, inside your `try` block.